# How to remove the last character in filter grid using Yii2 and Php?

Tags: list, yii2, character

I have this declaration for the filter in grid using Yii2:

```
$anno = Bibliografie::find()->select('Anni')->groupby('DaAnnoO')->asArray()->All();
```

Then the grid view:

```
     [
        'attribute' => 'Anni',
        'value' => function ($model,$key,$index,$widget) { return str_replace('-',' ',$model['Anni']); },
        'label' => 'Data',
        'width'=>'10%',
        'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
        'filter' => ArrayHelper::map($anno,'Anni','Anni'),
        'filterWidgetOptions'=>['pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true]],
        'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Tutti...'],

      ],
```

"str_replac"e works when I print the result. But it doesn't work in the filter list. What command should I give him for the list? Example: now is "1560-". I want to delete the last "-" from the list for every date.
Thank you

Comment: Try `ArrayHelper::map($anno, 'Anni', function ($model) {return str_replace('-', ' ', $model['Anni']);});` Not tested

Comment: It gives me a syntax error

Comment: what is the error?